# can anyone please guide with tensorflow in python and how should the scripts be run step by step

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to the python and below is the video which i was watching and i am trying to convert speech to text using tensor flow. can anyone please help me out step by step which very basic things as well. I have imported tflearn library and also installed tensorflow and few other required packages. below is the link of the video:-

https://youtu.be/u9FPqkuoEJ8

Comment: its not a big video, hardly of 6 min. if any expert around could watch it and explain me the steps please. would be very thankful

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is too broad to be answered here. With that being said if your are completely new to python and tensorflow, I recommend that you go through the good examples laid [in this github](https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials). As for help with python I would say just google it and most likely it has already been asked in stackoverflow or other similar sites.

Also, going through tflearn's [documentation](http://tflearn.org/) is a good resource. For example, the first tflearn method use in the code in the video is tflearn.input_data. This method creates a placeholder to feed data into the model. If you search [tflearn's site](http://tflearn.org/layers/core/#input-data) for this method, you'll see a detail explanation and examples. You can search the others (.lstm, .fully_connected, etc.) in the same manner. I hope this helps.

Comment: i have reached till training a set in this video, but now i am stuck on how to get the predict.py file which he is using it in the video